# method issue in java

Tags: java, methods

i'm learning to create custom classes and can't figure out where I've gone wrong

From main class...

`MyPoint p1 = new MyPoint(317, 10);`

the error says:

```
constructor MyPoint in class MyPoint cannot be applied to given types;

required: no arguments
found: int, int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

this is from my MyPoint class:

`private int x, y;`

```
public void MyPoint(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Why isn't MyPoint(317, 10) being fed into the relevant class along with the x and y values?

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Since when the constructor has a return value?

Comment: What do you specifically want to do?

Comment: Give the Definition Constructor is what is called when initialization u have defined it as method. i guess all will be right is following answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

remove return type from

```
public void MyPoint(int x, int y)
```

constructor cannot have return type not even `void`

make it

```
public MyPoint(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Comment: ah, completely spaced the return statement - must have confused it with some other work. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Constructors don't have return type. This is just a normal method you just made.

Solution: Remove the `void` from the method. It should look like

```
public MyPoint(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare parameterized constructor in `MyPoint` class.

```
public MyPoint(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Constructors must not have return type. So change your code as

```
public MyPoint(int x, int y)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```